# Promise doesn't work with jest in REACTJS

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I keep having a `TypeError: Network request failed` when I try to test a Snapshot of a component

here is the component

```
import {GetAllUsersPost} from './postdata';

    class ManageUsers extends React.Component{

        render(){
            return(
                    {...}
            );
        }

componentDidMount(){
            GetAllUsersPost(UserProfile.getId()).then((result) => {
                this.setState({
                    parsed:result,
                    loading:false
                })
            });
        }
    }
```

Here is postdata

```
export function GetAllUsersPost(id) {
  const json = JSON.stringify({id: id})
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(BaseURL + 'allusers', BdRequest(json)).then((response) => response.json()).then((res) => {
      resolve(res);
    }).catch((error) => {
      reject(error);
    });
  });
}
```

And here is the test file (\src__tests__\ManageUsers.test.jsx)

```
import React from 'react';
import ManageUsers from '../component/ManageUsers';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import Enzyme, {shallow,mount} from 'enzyme';
Enzyme.configure({adapter:new Adapter()});

  describe("ManageUsers", ()=>{
        const wrapper = shallow(<ManageUsers/>);
        const instance = wrapper.instance();
    let response;

    test("loading()",()=>{
        wrapper.setState({loading:false})
        response = JSON.stringify("")
        expect(JSON.stringify(instance.loading())).toBe(response);
    })
});
```

I know that my error is because of the promise (when Enzyme tries to shallow the component) but I can't make it to work...

thanks

Comment: 1. `fetch` returns `Promise` so you don't really need to wrap one into another. 2. I believe it would be better if you just mock `fetch` for your tests. As side-effect this would remove your Network error from happening

Comment: Thanls for that answer! Yes I tried that but I can't make the mock to work... Would it be like `jest.mock('../component/postdata');` before the wrapper ?

Comment: you need to mock module with `GetAllUsersPost` and provide mock implementation for `GetAllUsersPost` like  `return Promise.resolve(yourMockedData)`. Check [mocking modules](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules) section in docs, it should help

Answer (score 0):

Your test has to be set up as an async test. e.g.

```
it('should do something', async () => {
  const result = await myAsyncMethod();
});
```

Edited for clarity - **note that this is clearly untested**, but what you need to look for is something from the render method and state, since that's all you do with the results.

```
import React from 'react';
import ManageUsers from '../component/ManageUsers';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import Enzyme, {shallow,mount} from 'enzyme';
Enzyme.configure({adapter:new Adapter()});

describe("ManageUsers", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<ManageUsers/>);

  test("loading()", async () => {
    // wrapper.setState({loading:false}) // This should be a default
    expect(wrapper.find('something from the render'));
    expect(wrapper.state.parsedResults).toEqual('some result')
  });
});
```

Comment: do you mean somwthing like that  : `describe("ManageUsers",async ()=>{
    const wrapper = await shallow(<ManageUsers/>) });`